# How do you use the Kimono RESTful API to update parameters?

Tags: php, rest, curl, kimono

Specifically I am looking to update the URLs that are to be scraped. Documentation can be found here: https://www.kimonolabs.com/apidocs#SetCrawlUrls

Unfortunately my knowledge about cURL and RESTful APIs is limited to say the least. My most recent failed attempt was:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://kimonolabs.com/kimonoapis/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'kimonoapis/$api_id/update'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

where $data is an array of:

```
array(2) {
  ["apikey"]=>
  string(32) "API_KEY"
  ["urls"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "URL 1"
    [1]=>
    string(34) "URL 2"
  }
}
```

I have also tried variations of json_encode, passing the parameters in the query string, and different variations of cURL but have not be successful thus far. How do you successfully take advantage of their RESTful API?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @JohnSvensson the example above gives http_code 400, but so far I have not gotten as many errors per se as it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array('apikey' => 'API_KEY', 'urls' => array('URL_1', 'URL_2'));
$postvars = http_build_query($array);
$url = "https://kimonolabs.com/kimonoapis/{API_ID}/update";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

After a lot more trail, error, and Google this is what I finally got to work. Thanks for all the help @JohnSvensson

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$api_id` is not being interpreted because you are using single-quotes.

Example:

```
<?php

$var = "api";

var_dump(array('$api'));
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "$api" }
```

Related read: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Try changing the line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'kimonoapis/$api_id/update'));
```

To use double-quotes, or concatenate the `$api_id` variable `'kimonoapis/' . $api_id . '/update'`

Update:

Since the API expects JSON, you should do this:

```
$payload = json_encode( array('api_key' => 'key', 'urls' => array('url1', 'url2' ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
```

When using an array as you do, according to the manual `If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.` 
Hence the 400 error.

Update 2:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://kimonolabs.com/kimonoapis/");
$data = json_encode(array('apikey' => 'yourkey', 'urls' => array('url1', 'url2')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'kimonoapis/' . $api_id . '/update'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Good catch! I completely overlooked that. Unfortunately I still get http_code error 400.

Comment: http_code 404 when changing to multipar/form-data. Adding json_encode $data to the HTTPHEADER gives code 200, but does not seem to change the URLs.

Comment: You shouldn't change to multipart/form-data it should be as-is.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data), $data here should be the json_encoded of the array you had earlier.

Comment: Still 404 "Cannot POST /kimonoapis/" and removing that from init gives 404 "Not Found"

Comment: Are you sure "https://kimonolabs.com/kimonoapis/" is the correct URL? Shouldn't it be "https://kimonolabs.com/api/", "https://kimonolabs.com/apis/" or just "https://kimonolabs.com/"

Comment: That came from here: https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203276194-Tutorial-Start-crawls-via-the-REST-API
/api/ gives "Cannot POST /api/"
/apis/ and / gives "Not Found"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91120/discussion-between-john-svensson-and-fwho).